# Regular expression to match whole words

Tags: regex

I am trying use a regular expression in JavaScript to match instances of the word 'icon-' in a string and return the entire attached word up to the delimiter (space). An example of the string would be

```
ui-grid-ico-sort icon icon-up ui-icon-asc icon-user ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr
```

In this case I am trying to match only 'icon-up' and 'icon-user'.

So far I have tried \bicon- which appears to match every instance of icon- regardless of its placement in a word (4 matches) and \bicon-[^'"]+ which returns 1 match of everything after the first instance of icon-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(^|\s)icon-\S+
```

matches all words that start with `icon-`up to the next whitespace character.

You will need to remove a leading space character, if present. There is no other way because JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
(^|\s)  # Match start of string or whitespace
icon-   # Match icon-
\S+     # Match one or more non-whitespace characters.
```

Comment: Thank you for also providing the explanation

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression:
`(^|\s)icon-\S+`

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression:

```
\bicon-[^\b]+?\b
```

By using \b, this expression can also match the "icon-up" in these cases:

icon,icon-up
   icon,icon-up,icon-down

Comment: This won't work - he doesn't want `ui-icon-asc` to  Also `\b` doesn't work in a character class.